# Why is display:flex taking precedence over display:none in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries, flexbox

I have a flexbox style like this:

```
.myclass {
    display:flex;
}
```

and a media query like this:

```
@media (orientation:portrait) {
    .myclass {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

I would expect that the element is invisible in portrait mode, but this is not the case. In Chrome, display:flex takes precedence, even though the media query is more specific.

Why is this so?

EDIT: This only happens if the media query comes first in the CSS. In my app, this cannot be avoided because it's a rather complex MeteorJS app consisting of several SCSS files. If I repeat the very same media query *after* the display:flex, everything works as expected.

Comment: Hmm... Link please.

Comment: media query looks wrong. Is that surely the code?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/cworzpdd/)

Comment: I don't have a link as this is a local project at the moment. The media query is correct, I just simplified it (in the actual query, it also includes a max-height statement). I can see that Chrome interprets it correctly. But I found out that it depends which statement comes first. In my app, the media query is included first (since it resides in a different SCSS file), and the flex declaration comes after it. If I reverse order, everything works as expected.

Comment: Something else must be influencing the result. **The problem is not in the code given.** I changed Oriol's jsfiddle to reflect the order: https://jsfiddle.net/cworzpdd/1/

Comment: The order of the queries is influencing the result. But I don't understand why. I would expect the media query to overrule the normal class declaration, since it is more specific.

Comment: You answered your question yourself in your edit. Any definition after the media query will overwrite it. Your only option would be `display:none !important;` then

Comment: I tried the fiddle you made, but got the same results there. The "Hello" shows independent of orientation.

Comment: Ah, I see. So media queries are not considered as being more specific? This is a bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: CSS still cascades. Media queries are, to my understanding, more a kind of filter expression than an `if` statement. You could also try to tackle it from the other side. Give your `display:flex` definition a media query like this `@media (orientation:landscape){}`. This way it will only be visible when the device is in landscape mode

Comment: media queries don't add specificity to the CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

According to your edit your CSS actually looks like this

```
@media (orientation:portrait) {
    .myclass {
        display:none;
    }
}
.myclass {
    display:flex;
}
```

This causes the display property from your media query to be overwritten.

One approach would be using `!important`

```
@media (orientation:portrait) {
    .myclass {
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

But this can cause unwanted behavior in other places.
Another approach would be giving  your flex definition an opposing media query like this:

```
.myclass {
    display:none;
}

@media (orientation:landscape) {
    .myclass {
        display:flex;
    }
}
```

This way the element would always be hidden and only visible if the media query matches.